# Alguém pode me dar um help,não está validando o e-mail.

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#username').focusout(function () {
    //atribuindo valor do campo
    var sEmail = $("username").val();
    // filtros
    var emailFilter = /^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
    var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\/\"\[\]]/; 
    // condição
    if (!(emailFilter.test(sEmail)) || sEmail.match(illegalChars)) {
        $("#icon_ok").hide();
        $("#icon_cancel").show();

    } else {
        $("#icon_cancel").hide();
        $("#icon_ok").show();
    }  
});
```

***OBS: caso não digite nada, não surta nenhum efeito.

Comment: `$("username").val()` não deveria ser `$("#username").val()` ou `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Nossa mano, que detalhe !!! Muito obrigo !!!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss como faço para os ícones sumir caso eu não digite nada, pq qnd clico no campo e não digito nada, qnd clico fora, aparece o ícone, no caso como não digitei não era pra dar efeito nenhum

Comment: Como eu faço pra ele já ir validando conforme o usuário digita? Por que ele só valida qnd clico fora...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou um jogo da velha!! ao inves de `$("username").val()` deve ser `$("#username").val()`

Para não apresentar icones quando não digitar nada, faça um novo `if` e verifique se o campo não é nulo!

```js
$('#username').focusout(function () {
    //atribuindo valor do campo
    var sEmail = $("#username").val();
    // filtros
    var emailFilter = /^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
    var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\/\"\[\]]/; 
    // condição
    //verifica se campo não é nulo
    if (sEmail!=""){
      if (!(emailFilter.test(sEmail)) || sEmail.match(illegalChars)) {
        $("#icon_ok").hide();
        $("#icon_cancel").show();

      } else {
        $("#icon_cancel").hide();
        $("#icon_ok").show();
      }
    }  
});
```

```css
#icon_ok,#icon_cancel {
display: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="username">

<img id="icon_ok" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/82F83.png">

<img id="icon_cancel" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cR0t.png">
```

Comment: Galera, como eu faço pra ele já ir validando conforme o usuário digita? Por que ele só válida qnd clico fora...